# change database of osTicket

Tags: osticket

I am beginner with osTicket 
I have setup osTicket version 1.10 to my localsystem with create new db setup.
my question is, if we have another existing db of another osTicket and we want to use it then I have change db setting in location

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\osticket\include\ost-config.php
```

as below,

```
define('DBTYPE','mysql');
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBNAME','EXISTING_DB_NAME');
define('DBUSER','EXISTING_DB_USER');
define('DBPASS','EXISTING_DB_USER_PASSWORD');
```

is it correct way to change db,and if correct then any other thing is remaining to change db setting with osTicket?

and used version of osTicket will metter in this if I have userd v1.10 and in another existing osTicket has older version then this then will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should always perform an upgrade of an old version. Database could have been changed and it will not work with the new version probably. 
Here are upgrade instructions: [Upgrade and migration](http://osticket.com/wiki/Upgrade_and_Migration)